# place placemark in a map

Tags: jsp, kml

Currently I'm working on a project which requires to set placemarks. How can I do so?
I'm using JSP + Tomcat to execute the application.
Any response is welcome because I'm new to JSP and KML.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is too generic. You may want to post code. For tutorials and info: JSP - http://www.jsptut.com/ KML - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

Answer (score 0):

As a high-level answer I would propose to use the **Google Maps API** or the **Google Earth API** together with **Javascript**. This is a good approach to capture user interaction with maps and earth views, retrieve and process geographical user input, setting/displaying placemarks etc.

best to start [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)

[playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/) with lots of examples (earth, maps, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you need dynamical  generated KML, you shoud read about NetworkLink. It allows to add link as URL. Your app cat generated KML with placemark and via NetworkLink KML appears in GooglEarth.
[Read about NetworkLink](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#networklink)